# SPItemEventReceiver and code in other assembly

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, .net-assembly, gac

I have four projects inside my solution:

1. Class library,(.NET 3.5) called Common.dll
2. SharePoint project called *SharePointStrucutre* that has List definition.
3. SharePoint project that contains SharePoint job.

Both of them reference Common.dll, in both packages

4 SharePoint project with WebPart. I couldn't make it work with Common.dll, even when I have added it to a SafeControl part in web.config -  WebPart were just giving me message: This type is not safe and couldn't be imported. So I ended up just copying code from Common.dll to 4th project. (lame!)

Worst part that on my local setup, everything is working(WebPart is adding without any typesafe messages, EventReceiver works fine). Problem arise only when I am deploying to live system.

**Problem:**
In project *SharePointStrucutre* I have SPItemEventReceiver which executes Common.dll code. And it fails! 
Exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common, Version=1.0.0.9, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0dbfee127d760dde' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find 
the file specified.
File name: 'Common, Version=1.0.0.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0dbfee127d760dde'
```

I have checked GAC, and this assembly is there, everything was deployed just fine.

**Question:**

1. Is it a right decision to separate SharePoint projects, and having common library? Before I had it as one project and it causes problems with Upgrade and destroying already created lists.
2. How to reference dll in the right way ? So I won't have this kind of exceptions

### Important update

In my *SharePointStrucutre* I have code (HttpModule) that relays on Common.dll and it works. Problem only in List event Receiver. Only there I get message that dll couldn't be loaded.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One problem at a time. Let's try to fix the safe control.

Usually this error is just because you need to sign the project. So...

1. Delete all the code you copyed to fix this problem
2. Select the class libray project (common) from your solution pane
3. Right click on the project a select properties
4. Search for the tab where you can sign the project.
5. You will see a dropdown list with two options new or add existing (or something similar). I usually choose the key my sp project already is using, but make your choice.

Once you have done that you can use this library in any sp2010 project.

Now, go to your sharepoint project, the one with the webpart, add the reference and no message should arise.

And last, but not least, select the package in the solution pane, open it with the package designer and select advance. Here you have to add the dll from the class library by selecting the option "add output assembly from" or something similar. You have to choose where to deploy the file, normally into the GAC.

I think all these steps should make your problems go away... Good luck! ;)

Comment: Hello Gonzix, thank you for your response. I have signed my Common library some time ago, I created a new key with empty password. I'll try to sign with SP key, but which one of 3 keys I should choose ?

I've done steps you've described (to add dll into package) already. That is what I've meant by "Both of them reference Common.dll, in both packages" , sorry, I've been not very clear here.

Comment: What do you mean with 3 keys? I only have one key.snk file in my sharepoint project. I was refering to the key.snk file within the webpart project

Comment: Each of SharePoint projects has a signing key, I guess they are all different. If I am going to sign Common.dll with one of them, what about other projects that use this code? I can try to sign it with WebPart project's key. But my main problem is "Could not load file or assembly"

Comment: Are you deploying the 3 projects as separate wsp? If so, you may have prolems because the 3 are trying to deploy the common.dll into the gac and is messing the deployment. Try removing the dll from all packages but one and redeploy. Make sure you remove common.dll from the gac first

Comment: Yes, I have 3 separate wsp. I am deploying one after another. And I have checked GAC for my dll - it's there. And version is correct.

Comment: In my *SharePointStrucutre* I have code (HttpModule) that relays on Common.dll and it works. Problem only in List event Receiver. Only there I get message that dll couldn't be loaded.

Comment: The package that contains the common.dll reference in the list of assemblies to add, needs to be installed first.

Comment: I have two projects that reference Common.dll. And Common.dll is in GAC. And code that relay on Common.dll in both projects kind of working. It's only when I add item to a list, inside event receiver I get exception about missing dll. My guess is that event receiver is executed in some different context and this context doesn't see Common.dll